# Twitter BootstrapのModalダイアログ内のフォームをエンターキーでSubmitする方法

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

以下の様なソートのためのModalダイアログをTwitter Bootstrapを用いて作成しています。

```
<div class="modal fade" id="sort_form_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" data-keyboard="true">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/" method="get">
        <div style="display:none"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"></div>
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">ソート</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <span>ソート条件</span> 
          <div class="btn-group" role="group" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-primary active">
              <input type="radio" name="direction" value="asc" checked>昇順
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary ">
              <input type="radio" name="direction" value="desc">降順
            </label>
            <div>
              <select class="form-control" name="sort">
                <option value="foo">foo</option>
                <option value="bar">bar</option>  
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <input class="btn btn-primary" name="commit" type="submit" value="ソートする">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

そしてエンターキーでSubmitとESCキーでModalを消すために以下の`jQuery`を使っています。

```
$('#sort_form_modal').modal({
    keyboard: true;
});

$('#sort_form_modal').on( 'keypress', function( e ) {
    if( e.keyCode === 13 ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $( this ).trigger( 'submit' );
    }
});
```

これだとセレクトボックスの値を変えた後にエンターキーでSubmitが押されるのですが、Modalが開いた直後やもしくは昇順・降順を選択しただけではエンターキーを押しても何の反応もありません。

どうすればModalを開いた直後からエンターキーの入力を受け取ってSubmitを送るようにできるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enterキー入力でSubmitするためには、form要素内のいづれかのinput要素にフォーカスがあたっている必要があります。Modalが表示されたタイミングではどこにもフォーカスが当たっていないので、「Enterキーを押しても何の反応もない」状態になってしまいます。

解決策として、Modalが表示されたタイミングで、JavaScriptから自動的にinput要素にフォーカスをあてる、というのが考えられます。

Modalが表示されたタイミングで`shown.bs.modal`というイベントが発行されるので、そのイベントハンドラ内にinput要素にフォーカスを当てる処理を記述しています。

```
$('#sort_form_modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $('input[type="radio"]').first().focus();
}).modal({
    keyboard: true
});
```

これで、Modalが表示された直後にradioボタンにフォーカスがあたっている状態になり、Selectボックスの値を変える前でも、Enterキー入力でSubmitが行えるはずです。

なお、質問内の以下のコードは不要になります。

```
$('#sort_form_modal').on( 'keypress', function( e ) {
    if( e.keyCode === 13 ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $( this ).trigger( 'submit' );
    }
});
```

Comment: `shown.bs.modal`というものがあったんですね。`.modal({ keyboard: true });` まで呼び込んでしまうとページ読み込み時にModalが表示されてしまったので、フォーカスを当てる部分のみ追加するとうまく動作しました。また `keyboard: true` の記述がなくても`ESC`でダイアログを終了させれました。